# Basic captcha error in opencart

Tags: opencart

I have an opencart theme and installed to my server.The basic captcha is working fine on registration page and all the other pages except contact page.I have select the pages(like registration, contact etc ) from admin where the captcha to be needed.But still the problem not solved. Please help me out of this problem.
My opencart version is 2.1.0.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I solved the error. :)
I found path did not come correctly on contact.tpl (catalog/view/theme/OPC080182/template/information/contact.tpl)

So, I just edit the path from 
 to  and its work properly    :) :)